# CakePHP 2.0+ Setup on online shared hosting

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, web-hosting

1 and I've uploaded all the files onto the file server that I am using 000webhost.com however Im having a few problems with the modrewrite I keep getting re-directed to http://error404.000webhost.com/? 
Does anyone know how to setup cakephp 2.1 on a shared area??

Im getting this error now: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pluginsplit() in /home/a4300629/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 151` not really sure how this error has come about, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more specifics on how you've tried setting it up.  There are a lot of tutorials online (and some on StackOverflow) that show how to set it up on shared hosting - so we need more info to figure out where YOUR problem is.

Comment: @Dave  right initially i thought it was a modrewrite error but now im not too sure as i found that a lot of files were missing from my directory and Ive got all the files in there now but Im getting this error now... `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pluginsplit() in /home/a4300629/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 151`
not really sure how this error has come about...any ideas?

Comment: you're not going to make me repeat the exact same comment I already made, are you?

Comment: That is literally all I've done, I changed the mod rewrites to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp and then I got thrown an inflector class missing error which led to find out some files were missing then I uploaded the missing files and now Im getting this `error: Call to undefined function pluginsplit() in /home/a4300629/public_html/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 151` dont really know what specific details you require thats all i can say as thats all ive done :S

Comment: I've set up Cake (1.3 - 2.2) on 4 different shared hosts, and have never had to modify modrewrite.  Not saying your host isn't different, but - I'd try without modifying first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right I've figured it out, I followed the .htaccess instructions on this site.
http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/29628-help-cake-php-install.html
But firstly I deleted all the files and re-uploaded and this still didn't work until I used this .htaccess method.

Hope this helps anyone else who has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**After research on cakephp tutorial, which come to setting cakephp on shared hosting and it will work :)**

- move app, cake, plugins, vendors folder into your hosting root
  folder. It is user root folder on your hosting
- delete .htaccess and index.php on cakephp root folder
- move /app/webroot/*.* to /public_html folder
- delete empty /app/webroot folder
- edit /public_html/index.php to point to the ‘cake’ and ‘app’
  directories. For example my public_html path for my domain is
  /home/username/public_html, so i point
- ROOT to look at /home/username
- APP_DIR to look at /home/username/app
- CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH to look at /home/username/cake
- edit this line on /public_html/index.php with your appropriate path

> /**
>   * The actual directory name for the "app".
>   * Edited By Siraj
>   */ if (!defined('APP_DIR')) { define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(**FILE**))) . DS .'public_html' . DS .'app');
>
> }
>
> /// START --- Edited By Siraj
>
> if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) { if
>   (function_exists('ini_set')) { ini_set('include_path', '/home' . DS .
>   'username' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
>   ini_get('include_path')); //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'home' .
>   DS . 'username' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'lib'); } if (!include
>   ('/home' . DS . 'username' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'lib' . DS
>   .'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) { $failed = true; } } else { if
>   (!include ('/home' . DS . 'username' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'lib'
>   . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) { $failed = true; } }
>
> //// END

- The only .htaccess i have on /home/username/public_html, the setting
  for .htaccess look like this

> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]